# Disable upvote button in acts_as_votable gem after an up vote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, ruby-on-rails-4, voting

*Context:*

I have a forum thread model which acts_as_votable.
The up vote functionality works fine
The up vote button allows the current_user to up vote the forum thread only once, which is the desired functionality. I am trying to change the css of the up vote button to a different color once the current_user had clicked on it.

```
<%= link_to forum_thread do %>
  <h3>
    <%= link_to like_forum_thread_path(forum_thread), method: :put, class: "" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span> 
    <% end %>
    <%= forum_thread.get_upvotes.size %>    
    <%= forum_thread.subject %> 
  </h3>
<% end %>
```

*Problem:*

One way to do this is to get a list of all the user_id's(using @forum_thread.votes_for_ids) who have up voted the forum thread and check if the current_user user id matches the list. If so, then disable the button. Is there a more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Hey @newbie, I've answered to your question. Lemme know if you need any further assistance

Answer (score 1):

**Solution first:**

> @user.voted_for? @post

Its available in the documentation as well. [Here](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#the-voter)

**Now, lets go to the details:**

You current solution does the following:

1. Fetch all the votes on the Post. Ideally, see to it that you get MySQL to return as fewer ActiveRecord objects as possible. Because, there is a considerable performance loss converting each MySQL row into an Active Record.
2. Looping through all the ActiveRecords and collecting the USER_ID in it. Looping is another performance hindrance, if you could easily avoid it.

Instead, prefer a MySQL query that returns the ROW/Data of what exactly we need, "If the current user had voted on the Post". something like *(You would need to use the correct/apt database table names)*:

> PostVote.find_by_post_id_and_user_id(post_id, user_id).

The above returns if the user had voted or not.

Alternatively, Acts_As_Votable does provide the same without you having to do the heavy lifting:

> @user.voted_for? @post

Comment: Thanks Satya. '@post.liked_by user' - makes the @user like/upvote the post. I am looking for a solution to check if the current_user as already liked the post.

Comment: Newbie, always mark the correct answer as BEST_ANSWER if it serves the purpose. helps other people identify the correct answer. CHEERS

Comment: Thanks Satya. Your answer did not work for me. That is the reason I haven't marked it as correct.

Comment: I used the following method to solve the problem: @post.vote_by :voter => current_user . Then to check if the current_user has up voted the answer, the following condition can be used: @post.find_votes_for(:voter => current_user).size == 0

Comment: NewBie, check my updated answer. I've updated it yesterday. See if the code works.